# How to access my website on GoDaddy with just the IP address of my Web Hosting account

Tags: php, shared-hosting

First of all I am complete beginner in web hosting. This is my first time so please correct me if I am wrong.

**What I want to do:**
I have made an `index.php` file. I am sure I have written the php code correctly. I want this file to be hosted by a web host. I don't want to purchase a domain name for this. I want to access this file over internet via only the IP address of website.

**What I did:**
I purchased a web host account on GoDaddy. I didn't purchase any domain names for my web hosting. I uploaded the `index.php` file to the `public_html` folder. Now I am trying to access my `index.php` file using only the IP address of my website. Let's say my website's IP address is `166.XX.XX.XXX`. Here are the screenshots for my `website's IP address` and `File explorer window`:

[Website IP Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKYev.png)

[File Explorer - index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgY8e.png)

**What's the problem:**
I tried visiting `http://166.XX.XX.XXX/public_html/www/index.php` on my browser but I am not able to access `index.php` using the IP address. Its showing me 404 page not found error. If I try to visit `http://166.XX.XX.XXX/` its showing a `Coming Soon` page instead of my `index.php` page.

Is it possible to access my `index.php` file with just the IP address or do I have to buy domain name first.

Comment: Since you are on a shared hosting you can't access your website IP by server IP. Either buy a domain or find a free one

Comment: Domains are cheap. Just get one.

Comment: If you want to access your site using IP address, you need to purchase static IP. It will better to purchase domain name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I purchased a web host account on GoDaddy. I didn't purchase any
>   domain names

Three possibilities come to mind right away:

1. If you have shared hosting, this will make your site inaccessible by direct IP. In a shared hosting environment, the host (GoDaddy) will have multiple websites living at the same IP address. When a browser requests a website, the server relies on the domain name to determine which of the many websites to serve. Without a domain name, the server has no way to tell what the browser actually wants so you don't get your website.  To avoid this situation, you will need a host to give you exclusive use of an IP address.
2. Very similar to 1. The IP address you have is not the actual address of the server that has your site, but the address of a proxy server that performs optimization duties such as caching content or filtering bad requests. One such proxy service is Cloudflare. In this instance the effect is the same as in step 1: without a domain name, the proxy server has no way to know which of the websites it should proxy for and return to the browser.
3. Assuming you have exclusive use of your IP address and that the address is to the server that actually hosts the site, a setting on the server may disallow IP based navigation. I would contact the web host to explore remedies to this possibility

Comment: Thanks for the answer Beetle. I bought a domain name for my host and now everything is going fine :)

Comment: I know you've solved your issue but in the past if I had an account on shared hosting then I could use http://{ip address}/~{username}.

Comment: Its not working right now. you have any other option